# Where should I store global data for my multi-site WordPress plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

I wrote a plugin for WordPress which has a few user-configurable settings that are stored using WordPress's suggested method. I know they are saved in the wp_options table, but that is abstracted by the WordPress options API.

Now I'm trying to add a "global override" of the settings that can be configured in the Network Admin section of a multi-site installation. I found the appropriate hooks to design my settings page, however I can't find any info about where to save the data.

If I save it using the normal options API, then the settings get saved individually for each site. I'm looking for a place to save them globally for all sites, so the plugin can first look to see if the settings have been globally overridden by the server admin.

I can just write some code to write directly to the wp_options table of one of the sites (for example site #1) or even create my own table. I know how to do all of these things, but I don't want to do that if there's a preferred way to write mult-site plugins.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `get_site_option()`.  From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_option):

> Retrieve option value based on name of option. In multisite, return network option, blog option otherwise.

Comment: that looks like exactly what I need.  Is there any documentation on how to save the network settings?

Normal options are registered using register_setting - is there something similar for site options as well, or do we just roll our own settings persistance?

What I mean is that normal settings are just saved by registering them and then creating a form with action="options.php" and WordPress magically saves them.

Comment: You're confusing "options" with "settings."  Settings work with the [WordPress Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) and let you build per-site options pages without rolling your own solution. Options are key-value pairs stored in the database either per-site or network-wide depending on whether you use `add_option()` or `add_site_option()`.

Comment: i greatly appreciate your help.  If I choose to use site_options to store my network-wide values, then do I need to roll my own form and form processing functions to allow the site admin to save those values?

since "settings" has a good api for creating forms, I did not want to roll my own code for "options" if there was a similar api or mechanism for doing so.

Comment: sorry to be annoying with the follow-up questions, it just is difficult to find if there is an official way to handle network-wide settings for plugins.  If there isn't then I'll just happily go about rolling my own, but I wanted to be sure first I wasn't missing anything.  thanks again.

Comment: There isn't a built-in way to handle network-wide settings for plugins that I know of in 3.2.1 or even 3.3.

Comment: cool, thanks so much for answering my question - that's everything i needed to know.

Comment: After a couple of days I have to admit defeat with get_site_option - I can't get it to work for storing "global" settings even though it would seem like exactly what it is intended to do.  The built-in WP functions appear to be site-centric, whereas I'm trying to save settings for the entire server.  I'm just going to create my own table to store my global settings.

Comment: @Jason: WP indeed does not have an API for handling installation-wide settings. Networks of sites are the outer-most layer.